# Paypal Express shows a 404 error when returning to Commerce's completePayment endpoint

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to use Paypal Express with Craft Commerce. 
It sends us Paypal's login page correctly, with the right amounts, but when you click pay it returns us to this URL:

```
/index.php/actions/commerce/payments/completePayment?commerceTransactionId=43&commerceTransactionHash=cbcad33abe2cf99ea63c8ee49c0ee9af&token=EC-0N649078HJ025430W&PayerID=VAWBVKWL78DHN
```

but shows a 404 error with no other errors

I've tried using the show errors code mentioned in this post: 
[Handoff to Paypal Express with Craft Commerce](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19090/handoff-to-paypal-express-with-craft-commerce)

and I've tried it with Stripe which fully works.

There are no log error logs in PHP or Craft's logs, just a 404.

I've tried changing different products, different shipping types, I've uninstalled all other plugins.

It just fails with Paypal, and works with Stripe.

Any ideas?

Comment: No problem, Jeff... just my OCD kicking in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a variable name collision. You must change your [Craft token](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#tokenParam) name to something else, as per [documentation](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways#paypal-express)

Comment: Thank you so much Andris, and I'm so sorry for not reading the docs fully.